# Can a Matrix with positive entries have a negative eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It seems intuitive to me that the answer is no, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Can a matrix with positive entries have a negative determinant?

Answer (score 12):

If you look at the matrix $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{bmatrix},$$ we have its characteristic polynomial $$p(t) = t^2 - {\rm tr}(A)\,t + \det(A) = t^2 - 2t-3,$$ which clearly has roots $3$ and $-1 < 0$.

Answer (score 5):

Choose randomly and repeatedly a positive matrix $A$ until $d=\det(A)$ is non-zero.  If $d<0$, then $A$ has at least one $<0$ eigenvalue (why ?). If $d>0$, then swap two columns of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! For example, try

$$
\pmatrix{1&2\\2&1}
$$
It does have to have at least one positive one, though. For more on that, look for the Perron-Frobenius theorem.